# Does DownloadManager will work on targetapi 30?

Tags: android, storage, scoped

Cant find correct information about DownloadManager and scoped storage in API30.
How to test it?
I tried to change target api from 29 to 30, and all works fine, does this mean that I do not need to change my code to MediaStore?

P.S. I haven't in my manifest
`android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`

Comment: `does this mean that I do not need to change my code to MediaStore?` What do you mean? What has DownloadManager to do with MediaStore?

Comment: shared storage must be migrated to scoped storage. Does DownloadManager works as scoped storage?

Comment: Only for an Android Q/10 sdk 29 device that flag has effect. But it is not needed for using DownloadManager there.

Comment: You can use DownloadManager as before. I wonder why you just dont try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DownloadManager is still be working as normal in API30. only 2 methods are deprecated in API29.
refer to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager

[image]

also take note of the API30 change in DownloadManager.Request.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request
[image] [image]